# How to prevent Resharper of removing whitespace for new ()

Tags: c#, resharper, whitespace, visual-studio-2022

Resharper removes whitespace after runinng **Code cleanup**. What I mean is:

```
Person person = new (); // there is a whitespace between `new` and `()`:
```

However the above code after running **Code cleanup** becomes without whitespace between `new` and `()`:

```
Person person = new(); // no whitespace between `new` and `()`
```

Is it possbile to keep  whitespace between `new` and `()` after running **Code cleanup** of Resharper.
We are using:

- Visual Studio 2022
- JetBrains ReSharper 2022.2.3

Comment: Out of curiosity: _Why_ do you want to keep the space between `new` and `()`?

Comment: In the Resharper options: Code editing > C# > Formatting Style > Spaces > Before other parentheses > 'new' parenteses

Comment: @AstridE. otherwise warning is thrown with message *The keyword `new` should be followed by a space*

Comment: @KlausGütter yeah, it works! Could you post your comment as an answer. I will mark it as an answer with pleasure! Thank you very much!

Comment: Interesting, I haven't experienced that before. Is it SA1000 that is being thrown? If so, it looks like it is a bug (see [this issue](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/3329)).  [Microsoft's own convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new) is `new()`.

Comment: @AstridE. yeah, it is the same bug. It looks like it is not issued as [a release version](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/pull/3187)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is controlled by the Resharper option:

Code editing > C# > Formatting Style > Spaces > Before other parentheses > 'new' parentheses

Comment: could you see please this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74862181/spaces-are-not-inserted-in-visual-studio-before-new)