# Spaces are not inserted in Visual Studio before "new()"

Tags: c#, resharper, whitespace, visual-studio-2022

Recently t[his setting of Resharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74343253/how-to-prevent-resharper-of-removing-whitespace-for-new) stopped working:

Code editing > C# > Formatting Style > Spaces > Before other parentheses > 'new' parentheses

[image]

So when I run Resharper "Code clenup", then it does not add space before "new()". So my code looks like this after applying "Code cleanup":

```
object obj = new(); // it is not okay as there is space between "new()"
```

However, what we want is:

```
object obj = new (); // it is okay as there is space between "new ()"
```

Does anybody know how to add space between  "new ()"

Comment: Just curious: why do you need this space?

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy as there is [SA1000](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/3329)

Comment: It has been [fixed](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/pull/3187), so update the nuget [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.Analyzers/1.2.0-beta.435).

Comment: If this is in the current Resharper version 2022.3, you should report it to JetBrains.

Comment: @shingo feel free to answer and I'll be glad to mark it as an answer :)